# open a windows file directory for reading/writing in c

Tags: c, windows, memory

I'm trying to write the contents of a windows directory to a file using c.  For example, if I had a directory of jpegs (i.e. a directory that contains multiple jpegs) and wanted to convert them to a .raw file, I have something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

#define BLOCK 512*sizeof(BYTE);

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fd = fopen("C:\\jpegs", "r");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening device file.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int block = BLOCK;
    FILE * fn = fopen("new.raw", "w+");
    void * buff = malloc(block);
    while(feof(fd) == 0) {
        fread(buff,block,1,fd);
        fwrite(buff,block,1,fn);
    }
    free(buff);
    fclose(fd);
    fclose(fn);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is I don't think windows directories are terminated with EOF.  Does anyone have any ideas about how to solve this?

Comment: What is _"windows file directory"_? What is `jpegs`, is it a file or is it a directory? _"Or more generally, how windows partitions its directories and/or hard-drives in memory?"_ - I'm scratching my head now... The immediate question to you is: do you really know what terms _memory_ and _partition_ actually mean? I'm asking because they have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: it's a directory. sorry for the confusing language.  Oops, wrote that quickly without thinking about what I was trying to ask.  I guess what I was trying to ask was how windows directories are differentiated from each other in memory.  Or phrased another way, what exactly is fread reading from when I use fopen on a directory?

Comment: Because, when I run this script, it just continues to run and keep writing more bytes to the new.raw than are in the directory of jpegs.

Comment: Please, rewrite your question carefully, it is still not clear what is _"file of jpegs"_? So is it a file, or is it a directory?

Comment: You seem to actually have two problems here: first reading a directory and obtaining all of the files of a given type, and second apparently(?) a desire to do a conversion of .jpeg files to some raw bitmap format, and (possibly ?) concatenate them all into one.  Or else perhaps you are reinventing a primitive `tar` or `cpio` style archiver which just concatenates files without modifying them?

Comment: `FILE * fd = fopen("C:\\jpegs", "r");` is of course not going to work. The the file `jpegs` which is actually a directory only contains some meta information about the contents of the directory, its location in the file system and so on. But of course it does not contain actual data of the files inside this directory. In fact what you want is to enumerate all the files in this directory, and then for each file (in a loop) you want to `fopen` it, read it, and append its data to the raw file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix systems, although you can open a directory for reading, you can't really read from it unless you use the `opendir()`, `readdir()`, `closedir()` family of calls.  You can't write to a directory on Unix; even superuser (root) can't do that.  (The main reason for opening a directory, more usually with `open()` than `fopen()`, is so that you can use `chdir()` followed by `fchdir()` to get back to where you started, or use the various `*at()` functions, such as `openat()`, to reference the directory.)

On Windows, you'd at minimum need to use `"rb"` mode, but frankly, I'd not expect you to be able to do much with it.  There are probably analogues to the Unix `opendir()` functions in the Windows API, and you should use those instead.

Comment: Windows API does have opendir() / readdir() / closedir() as they are required for POSIX compliance ... something windows desperately wanted to do

Comment: @AhmedMasud: thanks for the information.  I wasn't sure whether those were part of the mainstream Windows API or part of the 'POSIX ghetto' where the POSIX functions get renamed with an underscore prefix because otherwise they intrude on the user's namespace.

Comment: Once upon a time, in a long obsolete file system type called 'Unix File System' which had a limit of 14 characters on the file name and 2 bytes for the inode number, it was possible to open the directory and read the names (and inode numbers, though there wasn't much you could do with them) using plain `open()`, `read()`, `close()`.  IIRC, you can find code like that in either K&R ('The C Programming Language') or K&P ('The UNIX Programming Environment').  In the days of 7th Edition UNIX, there was no `opendir()` etc interface.  That appeared with the BSD Fast File System.