# Open a directory on Windows: 'Permission denied'

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to get a file descriptor for a directory but calling `os.open` on on directories always result in a "permission denied" error.
I do not believe it's a permission issue because it happens on *all* directories, while there's no issue on files (See REPL session below). Running as administrator makes no difference.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.mkdir('mydir')
>>> os.access('mydir', os.F_OK)
True
>>> os.access('mydir', os.R_OK)
True
>>> os.access('.', os.R_OK)
True
>>> os.access('.', os.F_OK)
True
>>> os.open('myfile', os.O_RDWR)
3
>>> os.open('mydir', os.O_RDONLY)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'mydir'
>>> os.open('mydir', os.O_RDWR)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'mydir'
>>> open('mydir')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'mydir'
```

On linux it works as expected:

```
>>> os.open('mydir', os.O_RDONLY)
3
```

The docs does not indicate you can't nor any platform difference. Is this expected behavior? Is it not possible to get file descriptors for directories on Windows?

Comment: If it was possible, what would you do with those file descriptor? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574511/open-a-windows-file-directory-for-reading-writing-in-c

Comment: you won't be able to elevate your rights from within python. So to overcome this you need to run python with admin or elevated rights, to open your file.

Comment: What happens if you open a command shell with "Run as Administrator" and then try the same?

Comment: @thecreator232, Tom I think the rights as fine (the directory is even created by python in the repl as you can see). Running as administrator makes no difference. I have update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit:

This is not a permission issue, it will never work with Python 2. Python 2 is using the Win 32 API call `_wopen` when doing `os.open()` (code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c#L6554). According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx), it throws an error when opening a directory:

> EACCES
>    Tried to open read-only file for writing, file's sharing mode does not allow specified operations, or given path is directory.

So:

> The docs does not indicate you can't nor any platform difference. Is
>   this expected behavior?

It is expected behavior. I would say in this case it is fine that this detail is not clarified in the Python docs.

> Is it not possible to get file descriptors for directories on Windows?

On Python 2 you can use the ctypes module for calling arbitrary Win 32 API methods yourself. Python 3 uses `CreateFile` instead of `_wopen`, a more modern API call, which might enable you to do what you want, see below.

### Old answer:

The most important resource for this question is the documentation for the CreateFile Win 32 API function, documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You might want to read the relevant parts of it, e.g.

> To open a directory using CreateFile, specify the
>   FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS flag as part of dwFlagsAndAttributes.

Also, there is a comment below the docs, saying

> In order to open a
>   handle to a directory you appear to need SYNCHRONIZE access, even if
>   you aren't requesting any access rights.  (Note: this doesn't apply if
>   you have backup/restore privilege.)

Python 3 uses this function in several places, you may want to search for yourself

https://github.com/python/cpython/search?q=CreateFile&type=Code

or via git clone and using `grep -HR "CreateFile(" .`. In Python 3, there is the _winapi.c module which is most likely used when doing `os.open()` on Windows.

On Python 2, there is a call to _wopen in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c#L6554, but I am not sure where this is defined. When you follow this path, you will find the actual implementation. Then you can see how exactly Python is calling that function -- this, together with the docs, will most likely explain your observations.

Comment: Thanks. I feared I had to resort to using the win api directly. Though what you say about python 3; I don't think it's correct. I'm getting the same error in python 3.

Comment: Same Error in Python 3

Comment: Incredible they haven't fixed this after nearly 7 years! Especially since all instructions, even on [docs.python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) tell you to use: `dir_fd = os.open('somedir', os.O_RDONLY); def opener(path, flags): return os.open(path, flags, dir_fd=dir_fd)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have the right permissions on Windows (maybe you do on Linux.) This is from **http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-permissions#1TC=windows-7** and it tells you how to find out the permissions you have on a file or directory.

To check the permissions of a file or folder in Windows:

Right-click the file or folder, and then click Properties.

Click the Security tab.

Click a user name or group under Group or user names.

The permissions for the selected user or group are shown in the lower portion of the properties dialog box.